# Copiar automaticamente o atributo alt ao clicar em uma imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma galeria de imagens onde os valores do atributo `alt=""` são puxados do banco de dados. Preciso copiar esse valor automaticamente quando clicar na imagem para não precisar ficar acessando o código fonte e dando ctrl-C no valor do atributo. Alguem poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e inclua o código do que tentou até o momento.